# TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON in cloud function

Tags: node.js, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to use a firebase cloud functions from my flutter app but when I call it I have an error :

```
Unhandled error TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'Socket'
    |     property 'parser' -> object with constructor 'HTTPParser'
    --- property 'socket' closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at write (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/logger.js:12:84)
    at Object.log (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/logger.js:45:5)
    at /workspace/index.js:23:22
    at func (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:273:32)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

My function looks like this:

```
exports.sendNotif = functions.https.onCall((listId, convName, message) => {
    const payload = {
        notification: {
            title: convName,
            body: message,
            badge: '1',
            sound: 'default'
        }
    }
    listId.forEach(id => {
        functions.logger.log(id);
        admin.firestore().collection('USERS').doc(listId).get().then(snapshot => {
            console.log(snapshot.data().FirebaseToken)
            admin.messaging().sendToDevice(snapshot.data().FirebaseToken, payload).then(response => {
                console.log('SUCCES')
            }).catch(error => { console.log('ERROR') })
        })
    });
})
```

and I call it like this:

```
  sendNotifications() async {
    HttpsCallable callable =
        FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable('sendNotif');
    await callable.call(
      <String, dynamic>{
        'listId': ['10571112'],
        'convName': 'VYSgames',
        'message': 'Test'
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: Your function needs to return a promise that resolves only after all the async work is complete.  The promise should itself resolve to the data to send back to the caller.  Right now, your function isn't returning anything at all.

Comment: You are sending non JSON objects to firestore. You will need to serialize it first by following guide  lines [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json) before calling the funtion from your Flutter app. Also, what @DougStevenson suggested is a good point, you will need to return a promise so your function doesn't terminate unexpectedly